# How to test HTTPS rest from command line

Tags: linux, rest, https, weblogic

I'm having a problem I can't seem to solve on my own:
I have to request RESTful services but the RESTful services use HTTPs protocol.
I've created the client and it is deployed in WebLogic

I've downloaded the certificate using the browser and I've installed it in JAVA using the following command (In my linux server):
 "keytool -import -alias myalias -keystore /jdk1.8.0_101/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file certificado.com.crt"

I need to test that it works...
First, How can I test the RESTful services from command line?
Second, Do I need to install the certificate in WebLogic? If yes, How can I do it?

JAVA: jdk1.8.0_101
WebLogic: 12.1.3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The certificate must be installed on the system that's making the request. It's not about weblogic, it's about the local sertificate vault of the machine. You don't need to install the certificate on weblogic. You may want to take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/62496/ssl-certificate-location-on-unix-linux).

Then you can use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), just keep in mind that wget just makes get requests while curl do all types of requests.